# Algo for cash investment in stocks

Tags: algorithms

```
Given I have an initial capital of $10,000 and i want to buy shares in 3 different companies. 
Cost of a share in company 1 = $55
Cost of a share in company 2 = $68
Cost of a share in company 3 = $79
And, The trading platform charges me $30 collectively for three purchase transactions above. 
And, I want to invest 70% of my capital in company 1, 15% in company 2 and 15% in company 3
```

What would be non brute force algo to ascertain the total number of shares per company I can buy, that leaves the minimum capital amount after the 3 purchases ?

The problem sounds similar to 0-1 knapsack DP but its not quite that, i believe.

Comment: Does the trading platform charges you \$30 for purchasing of a share from any company? or is it \$30 collective for purchasing three shares, one from each company?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: @Inuyasha 30 is collective cost.